# Modular Lambda Function as a Cross ratio

Tags: nt.number-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry

What ie the meaning of the statement : Modular Lambda Function is such that,over any point $\tau$ in the upper half plane, its value can be described as a cross ratio of the branch points of a ramified double cover of the projective line by the elliptic curve $\mathbb{C}/\langle 1, \tau \rangle$

Comment: Which parts don't you understand? where have you read this? Have you read http://mathoverflow.net/faq?

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask

Comment: I have read this in:
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lambda_function

I can see it as cross ratio from the Legendre form of elliptic curve, but I do not see how it is that of the branch points of a ramified double cover of the projective line.

Comment: An elliptic curve has (affine) equation $y^2=f(x)$ where
$f$ is a cubic or a quartic.
In either cases there is a map from $E$
to $P^1$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto x$. This is a double cover, ramified
at the zeros of $f$, and also at $\infty$ when $f$ is cubic.

Comment: There is an excellent answer to you question in Yoshida's book "Hypergeometric Function, My Love".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elliptic curve $\mathbb{C}/\langle 1, \tau \rangle$ is an abelian group with a "-1" automorphism, given by sending each point $z$ to $-z$.  If we take the quotient by this automorphism, we get a projective line.  Another way to say that is there is an action of a group of order two on the elliptic curve that yields a two-fold cover of a projective line that is ramified at four points (namely the four points of order dividing two that are fixed by the -1 automorphism).

If we choose an ordering on these points, and choose the first three  (say $a,b,c$), there is a unique automorphism of the projective line that sends $a \mapsto 0$, $b \mapsto 1$ and $c \mapsto \infty$.  The fourth point will go to some number $\lambda$, which is the cross ratio of the four initial points.  The value of $\lambda$ depends on the lattice generated by 1 and $\tau$ (i.e., on the isomorphism type of the elliptic curve), together with the ordering on the four branch points (which basically yields a full level two structure).

If we take a suitable symmetrization of the $\lambda$ function under changing the orders of the four points, we get the $j$-invariant.  The cross ratio is invariant under the normal even Klein 4-group in $S_4$, so we only need to symmetrize over the quotient $S_3$ that acts on the first three points $\{ a,b,c \}$.

Comment: In his page http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/week229.html John Baez explains the way 4 points occur only once in the double cover of the 2-sphere by a 2-torus, every elliptic curve can be imagined to be. The fact that these 4 points can be chosen along the equator or as vertices touching the sphere of an ideal tetrahedron implies a relationship of the cross-ratio to the hyperbolic space with the sphere as boundary at infinity, something I still find mysterious.